Streamlit not taking more than one prompts for cohere model in OCI Generative AI
I am trying to use Streamlit. The first prompt works, but when I pass the second or third prompt, it is throwing this error. It was working before but has started showing this error recently. I am not sure why there was a quota limit I should be aware of during the streamlit session after a few usages. I have even checked the way the prompts are going, I even tried to NOT use create_history_aware_retriever  method and go with a streamlit chatbot without memory.
It still fails with the following error:

oci.exceptions.ServiceError: {'target_service': 'generative_ai_inference', 'status': 400, 'code': '400', 'opc-request-id': '62F4609E6A4349A3B312ED1D73380147/94883F1D68C1BD5711
8373ED41B882E3/A7E92505DFB5E7811684526204E71E51', 'message': '{"message":"too many tokens: total number of tokens in the prompt cannot exceed 4081 - received 20861. Try using
a shorter prompt, or enabling prompt truncating. See https://docs.cohere.com/reference/generate for more details."}', 'operation_name': 'generate_text', 'timestamp': '2024-05-
25T16:12:53.250556+00:00', 'client_version': 'Oracle-PythonSDK/2.126.4', 'request_endpoint': 'POST https://inference.generativeai.us-chicago-1.oci.oraclecloud.com/20231130/act
ions/generateText', 'logging_tips': 'To get more info on the failing request, refer to https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/tools/python/latest/logging.html for ways to log the
request/response details.', 'troubleshooting_tips': "See https://docs.oracle.com/iaas/Content/API/References/apierrors.htm#apierrors_400__400_400 for more information about re
solving this error. Also see https://docs.oracle.com/iaas/api/#/en/generative-ai-inference/20231130/GenerateTextResult/GenerateText for details on this operation's requirements. If you are unable to resolve this generative_ai_inference issue, please contact Oracle support and provide them this full error message."}

Here is the code:
import oci
import streamlit as st
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from langchain.chains import (
    create_retrieval_chain,
)
from langchain.chains.combine_documents import create_stuff_documents_chain
from langchain_community.embeddings import OCIGenAIEmbeddings

# """
# import fix worked:
# Before: from langchain_community.llms import OCIGenAI
# After: from langchain_community.llms.oci_generative_ai import OCIGenAI
# """
from langchain_community.llms.oci_generative_ai import OCIGenAI
from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate

import chromadb

if "history" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.history = []

load_dotenv()

# compartment_id = "ocid1.compartment.oc1..aaaaaaaacz66k7qusk5kg5wc4keajwvi2meiauw6wmyztmrb2tm6gt7tzqsa"
# CONFIG_PROFILE = "DEFAULT"
# config = oci.config.from_file('~/.oci/config', CONFIG_PROFILE)

llm = OCIGenAI(
    model_id="cohere.command-light",
    service_endpoint="https://inference.generativeai.us-chicago-1.oci.oraclecloud.com",
    compartment_id="ocid1.compartment.oc1..aaaaaaaacz66k7qusk5kg5wc4keajwvi2meiauw6wmyztmrb2tm6gt7tzqsa",
    model_kwargs={"max_tokens": 1000}
)

embeddings = OCIGenAIEmbeddings(
    model_id="cohere.embed-english-v3.0",
    service_endpoint="https://inference.generativeai.us-chicago-1.oci.oraclecloud.com",
    compartment_id="ocid1.compartment.oc1..aaaaaaaacz66k7qusk5kg5wc4keajwvi2meiauw6wmyztmrb2tm6gt7tzqsa",
)

client = chromadb.HttpClient(host="localhost", port=8000)
db = Chroma(client=client, embedding_function=embeddings, collection_name="ncert-eng-chromadb")
retv = db.as_retriever(search_type="similarity", search_kwargs={"k": 3})

from langchain.chains import create_history_aware_retriever
from langchain_core.prompts import MessagesPlaceholder
from langchain_core.messages import HumanMessage, AIMessage

# First we need a prompt that we can pass into an LLM to generate this search query

prompt_template = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([
    ("system", "Answer the user's questions based on the below context:\n\n{context}"),
    MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="chat_history"),
    ("user", "{input}"),
])

retriever_chain = create_history_aware_retriever(llm, retv, prompt_template)

chat_history = []

# https://python.langchain.com/v0.1/docs/get_started/quickstart/
document_chain = create_stuff_documents_chain(llm, prompt_template)
chain = create_retrieval_chain(retriever_chain, document_chain)

st.title(' Welcome to the ChatBot')
for msg in st.session_state.history:
    with st.chat_message(msg['role']):
        st.markdown(msg['content'])

prompt = st.chat_input("Say something")
if prompt:
    st.session_state.history.append({
        'role': 'user',
        'content': prompt
    })

    with st.chat_message("user"):
        st.markdown(prompt)

    with st.spinner('Thinking'):
        response = chain.invoke({
            "chat_history": chat_history,
            "input": prompt
        })

        chat_history = [HumanMessage(content=prompt), AIMessage(content=response["answer"])]

        st.session_state.history.append({
            'role': 'Assistant',
            'content': response["answer"]
        })

        with st.chat_message("Assistant"):
            st.markdown(response["answer"])

UPDATE
I noticed that it is to do something with the data, which is getting  retrieved from the data (NCERT CBSE Class 12 English Book chapters) stored in ChromaDB vector Database on locally hosted server in docker. When I ask something about the latest response by AI, it tries to fetch relevant information but messes up and gets some data, which has a lot of linebreaks. I think I would have to optimize my embedding criteria first to finally optimize this whole RAG code.

always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer (simpler to select and copy), and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

I used that code in another answer and the StackOverflow bot kept marking it as spam. Hence, I couldn't add the code here directly. Well that answer was deleted, adding code now.
